# Run mysql script through docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

Hi there,
I'm trying to create a docker container that will run a mysql script which generates a database and then table.  My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mysql:latest


WORKDIR /


ADD . /


EXPOSE 3306

CMD mysql -u "root" -proot < "schema.sql"
```

I create the image through this:

```
docker build -t database .
```

And then I run it through this:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 database
```

At this point the script should be run- however instead I just get this random line in the terminal:

```
 0b2503b42482a4fa840351925845392e1abdf6022b23447187ff49ed4f0fa05b
```

Grateful for your help!

Comment: Have you tried checking whether the server is running in the background or not?

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `0b2503b42482a4fa840351925845392e1abdf6022b23447187ff49ed4f0fa05b` because of the option "-d" in `docker run -d -p 3306:3306 database` which indicates that the container will be running in the background. You can remove it if you dont want that. 
For more info about this please check this link: [Docker run command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)
The container should be running though.
Check the command `Docker ps` that will show you infos about running containers.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

don't worry, this is `0b2503b42482a4fa840351925845392e1abdf6022b23447187ff49ed4f0fa05b` ID from container.

You can use id to stop or check status or collect information of container. if you want check your command is work or not, you can run with this command `docker run -it database bash` or `docker run -it database sh`

Hope this helps.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

as you are overriding CMD entry command in docker file, you would need to start mysqld service explicitly

```
CMD [mysqld, mysql -u "root" -proot < "schema.sql"]
```